Testing Symfony bundle working with API platform
I already made a test with a Symfony API project, and it works; now, I am trying to test a Symfony bundle working with the API platform, so I needed to bootstrap the app. But it seems it missed something because when I run a simple test on the user to get the collection route, I get the following error:

Provider not found on operation "api/users{._format}_get_collection

My kernel file
namespace ProjetNormandie\UserBundle\Tests;

use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\ApiPlatformBundle;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle;
use Exception;
use League\FlysystemBundle\FlysystemBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle;
use ProjetNormandie\UserBundle\ProjetNormandieUserBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait {
        MicroKernelTrait::configureContainer as private configureContainerFromTrait;
        MicroKernelTrait::configureRoutes as private privateConfigureRoutesFromTrait;
    }

    public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        return [
            new FrameworkBundle(),
            new ApiPlatformBundle(),
            new ProjetNormandieUserBundle(),
            new DoctrineBundle(),
            new SecurityBundle(),
            new FlysystemBundle(),
            new TwigBundle(),
            new MonologBundle()
        ];
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/packages.yaml');

        $loader->load(function (ContainerBuilder $container) {
            $container->loadFromExtension('framework', array(
                'router' => array(
                    'resource' => __DIR__ . '/config/routes.yaml'
                )
            ));
        });
    }
}

And 2 files loaded packages and routes
framework:
  secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
  test: true
  router:
    utf8: true

#api-platform
api_platform:
  title: PN User Bundle
  version: 1.0.0
  formats:
    jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
  docs_formats:
    jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
    jsonopenapi: ['application/vnd.openapi+json']
    html: ['text/html']
  defaults:
    stateless: true
    cache_headers:
      vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
    extra_properties:
      standard_put: false
      rfc_7807_compliant_errors: true
  event_listeners_backward_compatibility_layer: false
  keep_legacy_inflector: false

#doctrine
doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
      default:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        url: 'mysql://symfony:symfony@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony'
        charset: UTF8MB4
        server_version: 5.6
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
          ProjetNormandieUserBundle:
            is_bundle: true
            type: annotation
            dir: '../src/Entity'
            prefix: 'ProjetNormandie\UserBundle\Entity'
            alias: App
        dql:
          string_functions:
            ifnull: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfNull
          numeric_functions:
            round: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Round

#flysystem
flysystem:
  storages:
    default.storage:
      adapter: 'local'
      options:
        directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/storage/default'
    app.storage:
      adapter: 'lazy'
      options:
        source: default.storage

#security
security:
  enable_authenticator_manager: true
  providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
  firewalls:
    admin:
      pattern: /admin(.*)
      context: user
    api:
      pattern: ^/api
      stateless: true
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:
      - ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

twig:
  strict_variables: true
  file_name_pattern: '*.twig'

monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
      type: stream
      path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
      level: debug
      channels: ["!event"]
    console:
      type: console
      process_psr_3_messages: false
      channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]


api_platform:
  resource: '.'
  type: 'api_platform'
  prefix: '/api' # Optional

When in lunch test
<?php
namespace ProjetNormandie\UserBundle\Tests\Functional\Api;

use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use ProjetNormandie\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserTest extends ApiTestCase
{

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();
    }

    public function testGetCollection(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        // The client implements Symfony HttpClient's `HttpClientInterface`, and the response `ResponseInterface`
        $response = static::createClient()->request('GET', '/api/users');

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        // Asserts that the returned content type is JSON-LD (the default)
        $this->assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');


        // Asserts that the returned JSON is validated by the JSON Schema generated for this resource by API Platform
        // This generated JSON Schema is also used in the OpenAPI spec!
        $this->assertMatchesResourceCollectionJsonSchema(User::class);
    }
}

I have the error:

Provider not found on operation "api/users{._format}_get_collection

The bundle works when used in a Symfony project, but the tests inside the bundle do not.
